# Как передать GET ссылку (jQuery dialog)?

Tags: jquery, php

Есть php код, в цикле вывожу пользовательскую базу для редактирования/просмотра/удаления и т.д.
вот ссылки которые выводятся в цикле:

```
<a href="?act=massmail&code=".$exp[1]."&mail=ok">".$exp[0]."</a>
```

Как взять с собой все  GET запросы  [в модальное окно.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
Сейчас я просто ловлю это PHP

```
if ((isset($_GET['code'])) and (isset($_GET['mail'])))
{
...
}
```

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Взял из примера на оффсайте jQuery и как должно получиться:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p><?php echo $_GET[ 'active']; ?><------ Тут вывод 123 (GET)</p>
</div>
<a id="opener" href='?act=massmail&active=123'>Активные</a>
<script>
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });

        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Думаю должно получиться нечто такое:
<a id="opener" href='#' onclick="jQuery.get( '?act=massmail&active', { one: 'one', php: 'php', jquery: 'jquery' });">Активные</a>
Только это не работает

Comment: Уточните вопрос... Что должно происходится в модальном окне


Comment: в модальном окне необходимо выполнять редактирования всех передаваемых GET запросов. Это может быть и textarea и input.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю что вы хотите в диве модального окна отобразить наборы input'ов и/или textarea's которые есть в Url? т.е. 
в браузере в строке адреса введено 'http://some.domen.com/index.php?var1=value1&var2=value2...' и Вы хотите при открытии модального окна отобразить эти GET переменные в виде input'ов и textarea's ?

Comment: @srazil, Зачем по нескольку раз [один и тот же вопрос дублировать](http://hashcode.ru/questions/117696/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-onclick-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-get)? Для уточнений просто подкорректируйте имеющийся.

Comment: Да именно так хочу.